# How to distinguish between a SwiftUI Preview build and Cmd+B build?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode-build-phase

I need to run a Build phase only if an actual build (Cmd+B or Play-button) and not if the SwiftUI Previewer builds the app.

I did not find any differences in both types of build.